# How to close the window of "None of your preferred networks available" in keyboard only mode

Tags: keyboard

My trackpad is dead. I need to commit my repository with terminal. I reopen it, but it is still halfway behind a nasty window "None of your preferred networks available".

I am trying Command + W, but it closes the terminal, not the top window. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the window in question?

Comment: Nope :((, it is beyond my Mac keyboard mana

Comment: @Fyrefly It's the window shown when "Ask to join new networks" is enabled in System Preferences → Network.

Comment: Can you borrow or purchase a USB mouse? I always keep one handy just in case I need it.

Comment: though not elegant, but practical, a mouse can help. the touchpad finally started working again.